# Placing ticks in the middle of each grid in matlab

Tags: matlab, axes

I am trying to create a figure with axes on matlab. But I want the ticks on the y-axis to be in the middle of each grid. How do I do that? 
An example is like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could turn on both major and minor gridlines, but set the major ones to the back color like this:

```
ax = axes;
grid(ax,'on');
grid(ax,'Minor');
set(ax,'GridColor',get(ax,'Color'))
set(ax,'MinorGridLineStyle','-')
set(ax,'TickLength',[0;0]);
```

Which gives:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a specific matlab function to accomplish this.

As a solution, you can draw the grid yourself with vertical and horizontal lines at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ...

Comment: I thought that would be a rather common feature, especially since histograms and bar plots would usually require it.

Comment: Hopefully, someone else knows a better solution. You can try to look in the source code of matlab and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found another way by drawing my own minor gridlines and not showing the major gridlines.

```
figure1 = figure;
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,'ZGrid','on','XGrid','on',...
    'YTickLabel',{'','1','2','3', ''},...
    'YTick',[0 1 2 3 4 ],...
    'YGrid', 'off')

ylim([0.5 3.5]);
xlim([0 20]);
% gridlines ---------------------------
hold on
g_y=[0.5:1:4]; % user defined grid Y [start:spaces:end]
g_x=[0:2:20]; % user defined grid X [start:spaces:end]

for i=1:length(g_y)
   plot([g_x(1) g_x(end)],[g_y(i) g_y(i)],'k-') %x grid lines   
end
```

Output:

[image]

Credit goes to https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95511-in-matlab-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-grid-at-a-spacing-different-from-the-ticks-on-the-axes